# python fit a function dynamically

Tags: python, function, dynamic

I am trying to use some data to fit a simple power law function. The function is defined like below:

```
def fit_func(x,a,b,c):
    return a * (x)**b + c
```

Then I will read the data (x array and y array) from a file. I will divide the data into two parts, the average of one part of y array (yarray_2ndpart) is passed to c, where c is the argument of the fit_func. The other part is used to do the fitting like below:

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, xarray_1stpart, yarray_1stpart)
```

But I do not know how do I pass the average value to c?

Comment: Do you mean to pass the average value of part of the list as an argument to your `fit_func` ?...Can you explain more with examples...or more details...

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I mean. I want to pass the average value of part of the list as an argument to the fit_func.

Comment: you can use `functools.partial`

Comment: fit_func(x, a, b, sum(yarray_1stpart)/len(yarray_1stpart))?

Comment: @laltin I am taking a look at this routine. But would you offer more information?

Comment: @TomBarron I am using the average of yarray_2ndpart to pass to c. Not 1stpart. Thanks.

Comment: I assume sum(yarray_2ndpart)/len(yarray_2ndpart) won't work for some reason? :) Is the issue something about how to specify the slice you want to average? I'm not understanding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`functools.partial` doesn't create a real function and because of that SciPy raises error.

Another way of doing what you want is defining functions in place:

```
avg = sum(yarray_2ndpart)/len(yarray_2ndpart)
def fit_func(x,a,b):
    return a * (x)**b + avg
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(fit_func, xarray_1stpart, yarray_1stpart)
```